# How to show 404 error page in SvelteKit after route is rendered

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, custom-error-pages

I would like to show 404 manually after load() (in +page.ts) is already resolved.
Eg as result of streamed data or data loaded lazily on client side.

In such case simple `throw error(404)` can't be used, because it's caught only until load() resolved.